Efficient design solution for handling dynamic marking schemes with multiple levels and subjects
We're developing a grading system for a school with multiple levels (e.g., elementary, middle school, high school) and various subjects within each level (n subjects < 200). The challenge is that:
Dynamic marking schemes
Each subject can have its own unique marking pattern. This pattern might involve factors like:

Score: The base score achieved by the student.
Additional Data: Parameters influencing the marking, such as:

Date of exam (e.g., scaling for particularly difficult exams)
Age of candidate (e.g., adjustments for younger students)
Location (e.g., accounting for regional variations)
Monthly income (e.g., socio-economic considerations)


Shared Marking Schemes: Some marking schemes might be applicable across multiple subjects within a level or even across different levels.
Scalability: The solution should efficiently handle a moderate number of subjects (less than 200) while allowing for future growth.

Desired solution
We're seeking a Java solution that effectively addresses these challenges. Ideally, the solution should:

Flexibility: Allow for defining various marking schemes with different factors influencing the final marks.
Reusability: Minimize code duplication by enabling shared marking schemes across subjects and levels.
Maintainability: The code should be well-structured and easy to understand for future modifications.


Do you mean influencing factors will receive marks as inputs and will modify the value as output marks. e.g If a person gets absolute marks as 5 but he/she is of age 18 he will we awarded increased marks as 6  etc.(This variation could be in percentage etc)
